# Thread inside a 'while True' loop

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, computer-vision

I have this project where I detect driver's face (Real-Time), I'd like to combine it with an Age Estimation NN (Pre-trained model, developed by Tal Hassner).
The thing is I only want to send ONE single frame to the NN while keep running the rest of my code.. I tried using threading.Thread as well as multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool. 
It seems that the NN executed successfuly and predicted the driver's Age, however, as soon as it's done the 'while' loop breaks.

attached the relevant piece of my code:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
num_faces = {str(n):0 for n in range(0,10)}
CAP_AGE = True

try:
    while True:

        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if CAP_AGE:
            pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)
            async_result = pool.apply_async(predict_age,(frame,))  
            age_label = async_result.get()
            CAP_AGE = False

        frame = np.flip(frame,axis=1)
        (detected_img, rects, num_faces) = adj_detect_face(frame, age_label)


        print("Found {} faces!".format(len(rects)))

        cv2.imshow('Normal', detected_img)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

except:
  print('An Error Occured, Cannot Run The Program\nConsider Restarting the 
Kernel')
finally:
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Try putting parentheses around `cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF`

Comment: It'll change the logic of this sentence.. I wanna break out of the loop if 1ms has passed AND I pressed the 'q' button

Comment: It just breaks from the `while` loop or it enters the `except`?